# Operacion de valores agregar clase segun resultado

Tags: jquery

Tengo tres `select-option` con valores diferentes. Lo que necesito es que al restar los valores agregue una clase a la fila.

Éste es mi código (también disponible en [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L42r8mLk/1/))

```js
$("tr").click(function() {
  id = $(this).attr("id");


  $("#" + id + ' ' + "select").each(function(cSelect) {
    $(this).data('stored-value', $(this).val());
  });

  $("#" + id + ' ' + "select").change(function() {
    var cSelected = $(this).val();
    var cPrevious = $(this).data('stored-value');
    $(this).data('stored-value', cSelected);

    var otherSelects = $("#" + id + ' ' + "select").not(this);

    otherSelects.find('option[value="' + this.value + '"]').removeAttr('disabled');
    otherSelects.find('option[value="' + this.value + '"]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.js"></script>

<table id='example-table' class="table table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>UNO 1</th>
      <th>DOS 2</th>
      <th>TRES 3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr id="1">
      <td>
        <select class="form-control" name="select1">
          <option selected="true" disabled="disabled">Selecione 1º </option>
          <option value="1">1</option>
          <option value="2">2</option>
          <option value="3">3</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <select class="form-control" name="select2">
          <option selected="true" disabled="disabled">Selecione 2º </option>
          <option value="1">1</option>
          <option value="2">2</option>
          <option value="3">3</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <select class="form-control" name="select3">
          <option selected="true" disabled="disabled">Selecione 3º </option>
          <option value="1">1</option>
          <option value="2">2</option>
          <option value="3">3</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="2">
      <td>
        <select class="form-control" name="select1">
          <option selected="true" disabled="disabled">Selecione 1º </option>
          <option value="1">1</option>
          <option value="2">2</option>
          <option value="3">3</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <select class="form-control" name="select2">
          <option selected="true" disabled="disabled">Selecione 2º </option>
          <option value="1">1</option>
          <option value="2">2</option>
          <option value="3">3</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <select class="form-control" name="select3">
          <option selected="true" disabled="disabled">Selecione 3º </option>
          <option value="1">1</option>
          <option value="2">2</option>
          <option value="3">3</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Ahí está cómo es la estructura del HTML y JS. Al seleccionar los tres valores necesitaría que restara los valores de este modo:

```
valor_1 - valor_2 - valor_3
```

Y dependiendo del resultado, que dé una clase a la fila:

- (valor_1 - valor_2 - valor_3) = 0  addclass('Bien')
- (valor_1 - valor_2 - valor_3) < 0  addclass('Mal')
- (valor_1 - valor_2 - valor_3) > 0  addclass('Alerta')

Espero que me puedan ayudar.

Comment: ¿A qué fila quieres cambiarle la clase? ¿Podrías explicar un poco mejor esa parte?

Comment: al <tr> que tenga todos los valores selecionados, es decir los 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que faltaba era la funcionalidad de averiguar si todos los `select` en la fila eran seleccionado y hacer el cálculo.

Así está el JS adicional:

```
var faltanSeleccion = false;
var valor = 0;
var count = 1;
var allSelects = $("#"+id+' '+"select").each(function(){

    if($(this).val() === null){
        faltanSeleccion = true;
    }
    if(count === 1){
        valor = Number($(this).val());
    } else {
        valor -= Number($(this).val());
    }
    count++;

});

if(!faltanSeleccion){
    if(valor === 0){
        $(this).addClass("Bien");
    } else {
        if(valor < 0){
            $(this).addClass("Mal");
        } else {
            $(this).addClass("Alerta");
        }
    }
}
```

Éste código (también disponible en [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L42r8mLk/2/)) debe ser lo que quería hacer:

```js
$("tr").click(function() {
  id = $(this).attr("id");

  $("#" + id + ' ' + "select").each(function(cSelect) {
    $(this).data('stored-value', $(this).val());
  });

  $("#" + id + ' ' + "select").change(function() {
    var cSelected = $(this).val();
    var cPrevious = $(this).data('stored-value');
    $(this).data('stored-value', cSelected);

    var otherSelects = $("#" + id + ' ' + "select").not(this);

    otherSelects.find('option[value="' + this.value + '"]').removeAttr('disabled');
    otherSelects.find('option[value="' + this.value + '"]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
  });

  var faltanSeleccion = false;
  var valor = 0;
  var count = 1;
  var allSelects = $("#" + id + ' ' + "select").each(function() {

    if ($(this).val() === null) {
      faltanSeleccion = true;
    }
    if (count === 1) {
      valor = Number($(this).val());
    } else {
      valor -= Number($(this).val());
    }
    count++;

  });

  if (!faltanSeleccion) {
    if (valor === 0) {
      $(this).addClass("Bien");
    } else {
      if (valor < 0) {
        $(this).addClass("Mal");
      } else {
        $(this).addClass("Alerta");
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.Bien {
  background-color: green;
}

.Mal {
  background-color: red;
}

.Alerta {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id='example-table' class="table table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>UNO 1</th>
      <th>DOS 2</th>
      <th>TRES 3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr id="1">
      <td>
        <select class="form-control" name="select1">
          <option selected="true" disabled="disabled">Selecione 1º </option>
          <option value="1">1</option>
          <option value="2">2</option>
          <option value="3">3</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <select class="form-control" name="select2">
          <option selected="true" disabled="disabled">Selecione 2º </option>
          <option value="1">1</option>
          <option value="2">2</option>
          <option value="3">3</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <select class="form-control" name="select3">
          <option selected="true" disabled="disabled">Selecione 3º </option>
          <option value="1">1</option>
          <option value="2">2</option>
          <option value="3">3</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="2">
      <td>
        <select class="form-control" name="select1">
          <option selected="true" disabled="disabled">Selecione 1º </option>
          <option value="1">1</option>
          <option value="2">2</option>
          <option value="3">3</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <select class="form-control" name="select2">
          <option selected="true" disabled="disabled">Selecione 2º </option>
          <option value="1">1</option>
          <option value="2">2</option>
          <option value="3">3</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <select class="form-control" name="select3">
          <option selected="true" disabled="disabled">Selecione 3º </option>
          <option value="1">1</option>
          <option value="2">2</option>
          <option value="3">3</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```